# What is the meaning of "fail the trigger"?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have this problem to solve in Oracle:

The trigger should be fired before data is inserted, updated, or deleted in a row in the `ITEM` table. When a row is changed in the `ITEM` table, check to see if that row exists in the `ORD` table. If the `SHIPDATE` column has a value in the `ORD` table, fail the trigger.

What does "fail the trigger" mean? I am really confused.

I do not know whether it means that I would not update the table anymore,
or I would just raise an error message.

Comment: Please don't [delete & repost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052872/what-is-the-meaning-of-fail-the-trigger) your questions. If you do that too often you're going to get yourself automatically banned from asking further questions.

Comment: Almost certainly, Justin Cave is correct. It sounds like you're being asked to raise an exception. Incidentally, if you do raise an exception *before* an update, then this will cause the table not to be updated.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like this is a homework problem.  If so, you would really want to ask your professor to clarify the assignment.  We can guess but our guess may not match what the professor wants.

I would guess that the professor is asking you to raise an exception in the trigger.